# Strings not starting and ending with the same number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Before you mark this as a duplicate, please read! I am having trouble understanding the concept (which I need more clarification on than is provided) rather than just the answer:

> For any integer $n \ge 2$, let $S_n$ be the number of bitstrings of length $n$ in which the first bit is **not** equal to the last bit.
>
> The answer is $2^{n-1}$

But why?

In my brain, when you say that the first and last bit are the same, that means you are going to set aside two bits and make sure they are equal, hence $2^{n-2}$. Since we want only the bitstrings that **do not** start and end with the same bit, we can subtract this from all possible bitstrings, so: $2^{n} - 2^{n-2}$.
But this is wrong!

Similarly:

> How many bitstrings of length $99$ are there that start with $1010$ **and** end with $1010$?

Is the answer for this $2^{99-4}$ like above, or is it $2^{99-8}$? If it is the latter, how come?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh has provided a nice answer to your question.  Here is another way to see why the answer to the first question must be $2^{n - 1}$.  As you observe, there are $2^{n - 2}$ ways to choose the middle $n - 2$ bits.  We can then choose the first bit in two ways.  Since the last bit must be the opposite of the first bit, there is only one way to choose it.  Hence, the number of admissible bit strings is $2^{n - 2} \cdot 2 = 2^{n - 1}$.

Comment: This is also very helpful. While reading this I thought of another question. Mind answering? Take the first example I provided and mix it up: The bitstring **must** start and end with the same bit, however, the substring $1010$ must come after the first bit, whatever it is. So, an example would be $110101$ of length $n= 6$.  How many ways can this be done for $n \ge 6$? According to what you've said, instead of there being $n-2$ bits in the middle, there are now $n-6$ bits since we reserve a spot for $1010$. What about the first and last?

Comment: The first and last bit can be $2 \cdot 2^{n-2}$. So do we multiply this by $2^{n-6}$ and $2 \cdot 2^{n-2}$ as you and @SiongThyeGoh have suggested?

Comment: We have two ways to choose the first bit, which also determines the last bit.  Since four of the middle $n - 2$ bits are fixed, we are free to choose $n - 6$ of them in $2^{n - 6}$ ways.  Hence, the number of bit strings of length $n \geq 6$ in which the first and last bit strings are the same and positions $2$ through $5$ are occupied by $1010$ is $2 \cdot 2^{n - 6} = 2^{n - 5}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the first and last bit to be the same, yes, set two bits aside, but you still have to decide for it whether you want both of them to be $1$ or $0$, there are $2$ options here.

Hence $$2^n-2\cdot 2^{n-2}=2^n-2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$$

For your second question, it should be the latter. You remove the $8$ bits and there is no decision to be made for them.

Comment: Finally an explanation agrees with my logic. I failed to recognize that the bits haven't yet been chosen and there are 2 ways to do so, hence the multiplication by 2. Thanks!